# How to use ln -s to create a command line shortcut?

Tags: shell, command-line, symlink, path, executable

I have an sh file that I would like to be able to open from the terminal at any time. I would like to type "studio" into the terminal, and have android studio open

I recall using `ln -s` to do this, but I have forgotten and have already wasted much time searching the web.

Also, in which directory is the created symbolic link kept in?

Here is the syntax from my effort, command not found

```
ricardo@debian:~$ ln -s /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh studio
ricardo@debian:~$ studio
bash: studio: command not found
```

Comment: try `./studio`.

Comment: I want to make a link to ./studio that I can open from anywhere by simply typing in studio, or banana

Comment: If you want to execute the script from anywhere using `studio` alone, you have to put the link in a place that is being searched by the shell. The shell searches everything in `echo $PATH`. You can either change `$PATH` or put the link into one the directories of `$PATH`. What do you prefer?

Comment: e.g. try `sudo ln -s /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/local/bin/studio`

Comment: That last answer is exactly what I was looking for, without using path. Thank you

Comment: great. you may now delete this question. adieu

Comment: @Sebastian Please use answers to answer questions, not comments. And please do not suggest deleting questions after they've been answered. We're here to build a repository of answers that stay around and are useful to future visitors.

Comment: You may like the `alias` command, which is commonly used instead of creating symbolic links to shorten command names.

Comment: If you consider this question to be generic enough, please answer it to keep it for the posterior. I didn't think it was worth it. Cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command you ran created a symbolic link in the current directory. Judging by the prompt, the current directory is your home directory. Creating symbolic links to executable programs in your home directory is not particularly useful.

When you type the name of a program, the shell looks for it in the directories listed in the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like). To see the value of this variable, run `echo $PATH`. The directories are separated by a colon (`:`). A typical path is `/home/ricardo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` but there's a lot of variation out there.

You need to create this symbolic link in one of the directories listed in `$PATH`. If you want to make the command available to all users, create the link in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/local/bin/studio
```

If you want to make the command available only to you (which is the only possibility if you don't have administrator privileges), create the link in `~/bin` (the `bin` subdirectory of your home directory).

```
ln -s /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh ~/bin/studio
```

If your distribution doesn't put `/home/ricardo/bin` in your `PATH` (where `/home/ricardo` is your home directory), create it first with `mkdir ~/bin`, and add it to your `PATH` by adding the following line to `~/.profile` (create the file if it doesn't exist):

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

The `.profile` file is read when you log in. You can read it in the current terminal by running `. ~/.profile` (this only applies to programs started from that terminal).

Comment: +1 but as Winny's comment, I think an alias in `~/.bashrc` would be more straightforward.

Comment: @Sparhawk An alias would only work to invoke the program from an interactive shell, not from a script, a desktop shortcut, or any other program.

Comment: True, but the question states `I would like to type "studio" into the terminal`, and this is implied from the title and quoted commands.

Answer (score 4):

The most intuitive way to implement your wish is to use an alias. Type:

```
alias studio=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

or enter a related alias into .profile or better: what your shell uses as $ENV.

Note that you still may need to add

```
/opt/android-studio/bin
```

to your PATH to be able to use the software. The best is to first try out whether it works without an extended PATH.